# Selecting an option with Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, safari, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a website: [Arval.fr](http://www.arval.fr), and I'm having trouble creating the search tree.
The form has 3 selects: type, car manufacturer and car model, and they update depending on what was chosen before.

I'm using selenium to get all the possible options, and I managed to properly read all the options from the first box, but I can't get it to select an option so that the next one updates.

Here is what I've done so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.get("http://www.arval.fr")

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id(vehicleTypeRef))
select.options[1].click()
```

I'd expect that to select the second option in the box with the `vehicleTypeRef` id, but nothing happens. I've checked using `all_selected_options`, and the box is still set on the default option...

Have I missed something ?

Answer (score 3):

There are methods for selecting options

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id(vehicleTypeRef))
select.select_by_index(1)
```

For more methods have a look at the [docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.select).

> Edit

After trying it manually the problem is in the site. Selecting other option doesn't change the `selected="selected"` attribute

[image]

And after selecting other option

[image]

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't seem to work either, I've tried `select.select_by_index(2)`
 `select.all_selected_options[0].get_attribute("text")` and it still gives me the first default option

Comment: @Charleess Edited my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time, is there any way I can do it with selenium then ?

Comment: @Charleess `select.select_by_index` should change the selected option, but since it doesn't work even manually I don't know how you can do it with `Selenium`.

Comment: @Guy, AFAIK `selected` attribute means just that option is selected by default. It should not be changed after you select another option. @Charleess, `select.select_by_index(2) select.all_selected_options[0].text` works fine for me. Can you `import time` and add `time.sleep(1)` after option selected?

Comment: @Andersson AFAIK it should change acording to the selected option.

Comment: @Charleess, what exactly did not work? You cannot select new option with `select.select_by_index(2)` or option is selected, but `select.all_selected_options[0].text` still shows first option?

Comment: @Andersson I did not get any error message when selecting by index, but the second statement still gives me the first option...

Comment: @Charleess, I tried to run this code using 2 different environments and it work in both cases... Could you share exact code you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code,

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url = "https://www.arval.fr/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get(url)

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("vehicleTypeRef"))
select.select_by_visible_text("Voiture")

def getallcars():
    el = driver.find_element(By.ID,"makeRef")
    car =[]
    for option in el.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'option'):
        car.append((option.text).encode('utf8'))
    return car

cars=getallcars()

def printModel(cars):
    for value in cars[1:]:
        drop = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'makeRef')
        sel = Select(drop)
        sel.select_by_visible_text(value)
        time.sleep(2)
        el2 = driver.find_element(By.ID,'modelRef')
        print "The models for %s are:"  %value
        for option in el2.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'option'):
            if not (option.text).encode('utf8') == "Sélectionnez":
                print  option.text

printModel(cars)


select.select_by_visible_text("Véhicule de société")
time.sleep(2)
cars=getallcars()
printModel(cars)

select.select_by_visible_text("Véhicule utilitaire")
time.sleep(2)
cars=getallcars()
printModel(cars)
```

This will give you the output based on selection of all three values in first dropdown and models based on it.

Sample output:

```
The models for ABARTH are:
124 Spider 2p Cabriolet
595 3p Berline
595C 2p Cabriolet
695 3p Berline
The models for ALFA ROMEO are:
4C 2p Coupé
4C Spider 2p Roadster
Giulia 4p Berline
Giulietta 5p Berline
MiTo 3p Berline
Stelvio 5p SUV
The models for ASTON MARTIN are:
DB9 2p Cabriolet
DB9 2p Coupé
Rapide 5p Berline
The models for AUDI are:
A1 3p Berline
A1 Sportback 5p Berline
A3 2p Cabriolet
A3 3p Berline
A3 4p Berline
A3 Sportback 5p Berline
A4 4p Berline
A4 Avant 5p Break
A4 allroad quattro 5p Break
A5 2p Cabriolet
A5 2p Coupé
A5 Sportback 5p Berline
A6 4p Berline
A6 Allroad Quattro 5p Break
A6 Avant 5p Break
A7 Sportback 5p Berline
A8 4p Berline
Q2 5p SUV
Q3 5p SUV
Q5 5p SUV
Q7 5p SUV
R8 2p Cabriolet
R8 2p Coupé
RS Q3 5p SUV
RS3 5p Berline
RS4 Avant 5p Break
RS6 5p Break
RS7 5p Berline
S1 3p Berline
S1 5p Berline
S3 2p Cabriolet
S3 3p Berline
S3 4p Berline
S3 Sportback 5p Berline
S4 4p Berline
S4 Avant 5p Break
S5 2p Cabriolet
S5 2p Coupé
S5 Sportback 5p Berline
S6 4p Berline
S6 5p Break
S7 Sportback 5p Berline
S8 4p Berline
SQ7 5p SUV
TT 3p Coupé
TT ROADSTER 2p Roadster
TTS 2p Roadster
TTS 3p Coupé
The models for BMW are:
Série 1 3p Berline
Série 1 5p Berline
Série 2 2p Coupé
Série 2 Active Tourer 5p Monovolume
Série 2 Cabriolet 2p Cabriolet
Série 2 Gran Tourer 5p Monovolume
Série 3 4p Berline
Série 3 Gran Turismo 5p Berline
Série 3 Touring 5p Break
Série 4 2p Cabriolet
Série 4 2p Coupé
Série 4 Gran Coupé 5p Berline
Série 5 4p Berline
Série 5 Gran Turismo 5p Berline
Série 5 Touring 5p Break
Série 6 2p Cabriolet
Série 6 2p Coupé
Série 6 Gran Coupé 4p Berline
Série 7 4p Berline
Série 7 Limousine 4p Berline
X1 5p SUV
X3 5p SUV
X4 5p SUV
X5 5p SUV
X6 5p SUV
Z4 2p Roadster
i3 5p Berline
i8 2p Coupé
The models for CITROEN are:
Berlingo Multispace 5p Monovolume
C-Elysée 4p Berline
C-Zero 5p Berline
C1 3p Berline
C1 5p Berline
C3 5p Berline
C3 Picasso 5p Monovolume
C4 5p Berline
C4 Aircross 5p SUV
C4 Cactus 5p Berline
C4 Picasso 5p Monovolume
C5 4p Berline
C5 Tourer 5p Break
C5 Tourer XTR 5p Break
E-Mehari 3p Cabriolet
Grand C4 Picasso 5p Monospace (MPV)
Jumper 4p Combi
Nemo Multispace 4p Monovolume
Nemo Multispace 5p Monovolume
Spacetourer 4p Monospace (MPV)
Spacetourer 5p Monospace (MPV)
The models for DACIA are:
Dokker 4p Monovolume
Dokker 5p Monovolume
Duster 5p SUV
Lodgy 5 Places 5p Monospace (MPV)
Lodgy 7 Places 5p Monospace (MPV)
Logan 4p Berline
Logan MCV 5p Break
Sandero 5p Berline
The models for DS are:
DS 3 3p Berline
DS 3 Cabriolet 2p Cabriolet
DS 4 5p Berline
DS 4 Crossback 5p Berline
DS 5 5p Berline
DS 7 Crossback 5p SUV
The models for FERRARI are:
488 2p Cabriolet
488 2p Coupé
California 2p Cabriolet
F12 3p Coupé
GTC4 3p Berline
The models for FIAT are:
124 Spider 2p Cabriolet
500 3p Berline
500C 2p Cabriolet
500L 5p Monovolume
500L Living 5p Monovolume
500X 5p SUV
Doblò 5p Monovolume
Doblò Cargo 5p Combi
Ducato 4p Combi
Fiorino 4p Combi
Fiorino 5p Combi
Freemont 5p SUV
Fullback 4p Plateau double cabine
Idea 5p Monovolume
Panda 5p Berline
Panda 5p SUV
Punto 5p Berline
Qubo 5p Monovolume
Talento 4p Combi
Tipo 4p Berline
Tipo 5p Berline
Tipo Station Wagon 5p Break
The models for FORD are:
B-MAX 5p Monovolume
C-Max 5p Monovolume
Ecosport 5p SUV
Edge 5p SUV
Fiesta 3p Berline
Fiesta 5p Berline
Focus 5p Berline
Focus SW 5p Break
Galaxy 5p Monospace
Grand C-MAX 5p Monovolume
Grand Tourneo Connect 5p Monospace (MPV)
KA+ 5p Berline
Kuga 5p SUV
Mondeo 4p Berline
Mondeo 5p Berline
Mondeo SW 5p Break
Mustang 2p Cabriolet
Mustang 2p Coupé
Ranger 4p Pick-up
Ranger DC 4p Pick-up
S-Max 5p Monospace
Tourneo Connect 5p Monovolume
Tourneo Courier 5p Monovolume
Tourneo Custom 5p Combi
Transit 4p Combi
Transit Custom 4p Combi
The models for HONDA are:
CR-V 5p SUV
Civic 4p Berline
Civic 5p Berline
Civic Tourer 5p Break
Civic Type R 5p Berline
HR-V 5p SUV
Jazz 5p Berline
NSX 2p Coupé
The models for HYUNDAI are:
Ioniq 5p Berline
Santa Fe 5p SUV
Tucson 5p SUV
i10 5p Berline
i20 5p Berline
i30 5p Berline
i40 4p Berline
i40 Sport Wagon 5p Break
ix20 5p Monovolume
The models for INFINITI are:
Q30 5p Berline
Q50 4p Berline
Q60 2p Coupé
Q70 4p Berline
QX30 5p Crossover
QX50 5p SUV
QX70 5p SUV
The models for JAGUAR are:
F-PACE 5p SUV
F-Type 2p Cabriolet
F-Type 3p Coupé
XE 4p Berline
XF 4p Berline
XJ 4p Berline
The models for JEEP are:
Cherokee 5p SUV
Grand Cherokee 5p SUV
Renegade 5p SUV
Wrangler 2p SUV
Wrangler Unlimited 4p SUV
The models for KIA are:
Carens 5p Monovolume
Niro 5p Berline
Optima 4p Berline
Optima 5p Break
Picanto 5p Berline
Rio 5p Berline
Sorento 5p SUV
Soul 5p Berline
Sportage 5p SUV
Venga 5p Monovolume
cee'd 5p Berline
cee'd_SW 5p Break
pro-cee'd 3p Berline
The models for LADA are:
4X4 3p SUV
Priora 5p Berline
Priora 5p Break
The models for LANCIA are:
Delta 5p Berline
Voyager 5p Monospace (MPV)
Ypsilon 5p Berline
The models for LAND ROVER are:
Discovery 5p SUV
Discovery Sport 5p SUV
Range Rover 5p SUV
Range Rover Evoque 5p SUV
Range Rover Evoque Cabriolet 2p SUV
Range Rover Evoque Coupe 3p SUV
Range Rover Sport 5p SUV
The models for LEXUS are:
CT 5p Berline
GS 4p Berline
IS 4p Berline
LS 4p Berline
NX 5p SUV
RC 2p Coupé
RX 5p SUV
The models for LOTUS are:
Elise 2p Roadster
Evora 2p Coupé
Exige 2p Coupé
The models for MASERATI are:
Ghibli 4p Berline
GranTurismo 2p Coupé
Levante 5p SUV
Quattroporte 4p Berline
The models for MAZDA are:
CX-3 5p Crossover
CX-5 5p SUV
MX-5 2p Cabriolet
MX-5 2p Roadster
Mazda2 5p Berline
Mazda3 5p Berline
Mazda6 4p Berline
Mazda6 5p Break
The models for MERCEDES-BENZ are:
AMG GT 3p Coupé
Citan 5p Combi
Classe A 5p Berline
Classe B 5p Monovolume
Classe C 2p Coupé
Classe C 4p Berline
Classe C 5p Break
Classe C Cabriolet 2p Cabriolet
Classe CLA 4p Coupé
Classe CLA Shooting Brake 5p Break
Classe CLS 4p Coupé
Classe CLS Shooting Brake 5p Break
Classe E 2p Cabriolet
Classe E 2p Coupé
Classe E 4p Berline
Classe E 5p Break
Classe G 5p SUV
Classe GLA 5p SUV
Classe GLC 5p SUV
Classe GLE 5p SUV
Classe GLE Coupe 5p SUV
Classe GLS 5p SUV
Classe S 2p Coupé
Classe S 4p Berline
Classe S Cabriolet 2p Cabriolet
Classe S Limousine 4p Berline
Classe SL Roadster 2p Roadster
Classe V Compact 4p Monospace (MPV)
Classe V Compact 5p Monospace (MPV)
Classe V Extra-Long 4p Monospace (MPV)
Classe V Extra-Long 5p Monospace (MPV)
Classe V Long 4p Monospace (MPV)
Classe V Long 5p Monospace (MPV)
GLC Coupe 5p Coupé
Marco Polo 4p Van loisirs
Mercedes-Maybach S 4p Berline
SLC 2p Roadster
Vito Tourer Compact 4p Combi
Vito Tourer Extra Long 4p Combi
Vito Tourer Long 4p Combi
The models for MINI are:
Clubman 5p Break
Mini 2p Cabriolet
Mini 3p Berline
Mini 5p Berline
Paceman 3p Crossover
The models for MITSUBISHI are:
ASX 5p SUV
I 5p Berline
L200 VU 4p Plateau double cabine
Outlander 5p SUV
Outlander PHEV 5p SUV
Pajero 3p SUV
Pajero 5p SUV
Space Star 5p Berline
The models for NISSAN are:
370Z 2p Cabriolet
370Z 3p Coupé
Evalia 5p Monovolume
GT-R 2p Coupé
Juke 5p Crossover
LEAF 5p Berline
Micra 5p Berline
NV200 5p Combi
NV300 5p Combi
NV400 4p Combi
Navara VU 4p Plateau double cabine
Note 5p Monovolume
Pulsar 5p Berline
Qashqai 5p Crossover
X-TRAIL 5p Crossover
e-NV200 Evalia 5p Monovolume
The models for OPEL are:
Adam 3p Berline
Astra 5p Berline
Astra Sports Tourer 5p Break
Cascada 2p Cabriolet
Combo Tour 5p Monovolume
Corsa 3p Berline
Corsa 5p Berline
GTC 3p Berline
GTC OPC 3p Berline
Insignia 5p Berline
Insignia Business Edition 5p Berline
Insignia Business Edition 5p Break
Insignia Sports Tourer 5p Break
Karl 5p Berline
Meriva 5p Monovolume
Mokka X 5p SUV
Movano VU 4p Combi
Vivaro 4p Combi
Vivaro 5p Combi
Zafira 5p Monovolume
The models for PEUGEOT are:
108 3p Berline
108 5p Berline
2008 5p Crossover
208 3p Berline
208 5p Berline
3008 5p SUV
308 5p Berline
308 SW 5p Break
4008 5p SUV
5008 5p SUV
508 4p Berline
508 RXH 5p Break
508 SW 5p Break
Bipper Tepee 5p Monovolume
Boxer 4p Combi
Expert 4p Combi
Partner Tepee 4p Monovolume
Partner Tepee 5p Monovolume
Traveller 4p Monospace (MPV)
Traveller 5p Monospace (MPV)
iOn 5p Berline
The models for PORSCHE are:
718 Boxster 2p Roadster
718 Cayman 3p Coupé
911 2p Cabriolet
911 2p Coupé
911 2p Roadster
Cayenne 5p SUV
Macan 5p SUV
Panamera 5p Berline
The models for RENAULT are:
Captur 5p Crossover
Clio 5p Berline
Clio Estate 5p Break
Espace 5p Crossover
Grand Kangoo 5p Monospace (MPV)
Grand Scénic 5p Monovolume
Kadjar 5p Crossover
Kangoo 5p Monovolume
Kangoo Express 4p Combi
Master 4p Combi
Mégane 5p Berline
Mégane Estate 5p Break
Scénic 5p Monovolume
Talisman 4p Berline
Talisman Estate 5p Break
Trafic 4p Combi
Trafic 5p Combi
Twingo 5p Berline
ZOE 5p Berline
The models for ROLLS-ROYCE are:
Ghost 4p Berline
Phantom 2p Cabriolet
Phantom 4p Berline
The models for SEAT are:
Alhambra 5p Monospace (MPV)
Ateca 5p SUV
Ibiza 5p Berline
Ibiza Cupra 3p Berline
Leon 5p Berline
Leon Cupra 5p Berline
Leon Cupra SC 3p Berline
Leon Cupra ST 5p Break
Leon SC 3p Berline
Leon ST 5p Break
MII 3p Berline
MII 5p Berline
Toledo 5p Berline
The models for SKODA are:
Citigo 3p Berline
Citigo 5p Berline
Fabia 5p Berline
Fabia Combi 5p Break
Kodiaq 5p SUV
Octavia 5p Berline
Octavia Combi 5p Break
Rapid 5p Berline
Rapid Spaceback 5p Berline
Superb 5p Berline
Superb Combi 5p Break
Yeti 5p SUV
The models for SMART are:
Forfour 5p Berline
Fortwo 2p Cabriolet
Fortwo 3p Coupé
The models for SSANGYONG are:
Actyon Sports 4p Pick-up
Korando 5p SUV
Rexton 5p SUV
Rodius 5p Monospace (MPV)
Tivoli 5p SUV
Tivoli xlv 5p SUV
The models for SUBARU are:
BRZ 2p Coupé
Forester 5p SUV
Forester Sport 5p SUV
Levorg 5p Break
Outback 5p Break
WRX STI 4p Berline
XV 5p SUV
The models for SUZUKI are:
BALENO 5p Berline
Celerio 5p Berline
Ignis 5p Berline
Jimny 3p SUV
S-CROSS 5p SUV
Swift 3p Berline
Swift 5p Berline
Vitara 5p SUV
The models for TESLA are:
Model S 4p Berline
Model S 5p Berline
Model X 5p SUV
The models for TOYOTA are:
Auris 5p Berline
Auris Touring Sports 5p Break
Avensis 4p Berline
Avensis Touring Sports 5p Break
Aygo 3p Berline
Aygo 5p Berline
C-HR 5p SUV
GT86 MC 2p Coupé
Hilux DC 4p Plateau double cabine
Landcruiser 3p SUV
Landcruiser 5p SUV
Prius 5p Berline
Prius+ 5p Monovolume
Proace 4p Combi
Proace Verso 5p Monospace (MPV)
RAV4 5p SUV
RAV4 Hybride 5p SUV
Verso 5p Monovolume
Yaris 3p Berline
Yaris 5p Berline
Yaris Hybride 5p Berline
The models for VOLKSWAGEN are:
Amarok DC 4p Plateau double cabine
CC 4p Berline
Caddy 4p Monovolume
Caddy 5p Monovolume
Caddy Maxi 5p Monovolume
California 4p Van loisirs
Caravelle 4p Combi
Caravelle 5p Combi
Coccinelle 2p Cabriolet
Coccinelle 3p Berline
Eos 2p Cabriolet
Golf 2p Cabriolet
Golf 3p Berline
Golf 3p Berline
Golf 5p Berline
Golf 5p Berline
Golf SW 5p Break
Golf Sportsvan 5p Monovolume
Jetta 4p Berline
Multivan 4p Combi
Multivan 5p Combi
Passat 4p Berline
Passat SW 5p Break
Polo 3p Berline
Polo 5p Berline
Scirocco 3p Coupé
Sharan 5p Monospace (MPV)
Tiguan 5p SUV
Touareg 5p SUV
Touran 5p Monovolume
Up 5p Berline
up 3p Berline
The models for VOLVO are:
S60 4p Berline
S90 4p Berline
V40 5p Berline
V40 CROSS COUNTRY 5p Berline
V60 5p Break
V60 Cross Country 5p Break
V60 PLUG-IN HYBRID 5p Break
V90 5p Break
V90 CROSS COUNTRY 5p Break
XC60 5p SUV
XC90 5p SUV
The models for ALFA ROMEO are:
Giulietta VU 5p Berline
The models for BMW are:
Série 1 VU 3p Berline
Série 1 VU 5p Berline
Série 2 Gran Tourer VU 5p Fourgonnette
The models for CITROEN are:
C3 Société VU 5p Berline
C4 Cactus VU 5p Berline
C4 Société VU 5p Berline
The models for FIAT are:
500 VU 3p Berline
500L VU 5p Fourgonnette
500L VU 5p Monovolume
Panda VU 5p Berline
Punto VU 5p Berline
Strada VU 2p Cabriolet
Tipo VU 5p Berline
The models for FORD are:
Fiesta Affaires VU 3p Berline
The models for LANCIA are:
Delta VU 5p Berline
Ypsilon VU 5p Berline
The models for MINI are:
Mini VU 3p Berline
Mini VU 5p Berline
The models for OPEL are:
Astra Sports Tourer VU 5p Fourgon vitré
Astra VU 5p Berline
Corsa VU 3p Berline
Corsa VU 5p Berline
The models for PEUGEOT are:
208 Affaire VU 5p Berline
208 VU 5p Berline
308 Affaire VU 5p Berline
308 SW VU 5p Break
308 VU 5p Berline
The models for RENAULT are:
Clio Société VU 5p Berline
Mégane Société VU 5p Berline
The models for TOYOTA are:
Auris VU 5p Berline
Yaris Hybride Affaires VU 5p Berline
Yaris affaires VU 3p Berline
Yaris affaires VU 5p Berline
The models for VOLKSWAGEN are:
Golf VU 3p Berline
Golf VU 5p Berline
Polo VU 3p Berline
Polo VU 5p Berline
The models for CITROEN are:
Berlingo Cabine Approfondie VU 4p Fourgonnette
Berlingo Plancher Cabine VU 2p Plancher cabine
Berlingo VU 3p Fourgonnette
Berlingo VU 4p Fourgonnette
Jumper Benne SC VU 2p Pick-up
Jumper CA VU 4p Fourgon
Jumper Châssis Cabine DC VU 4p Châssis double cabine
Jumper Châssis Cabine SC VU 2p Châssis cabine
Jumper Plancher SC VU 2p Plancher cabine
Jumper Plateau Ridelles DC VU 4p Plateau double cabine
Jumper Plateau Ridelles SC VU 2p Plateau
Jumper VU 4p Fourgon
Jumper VU 4p Fourgon vitré
Jumpy VU 2p Plancher cabine
Jumpy VU 4p Fourgon
Nemo VU 3p Fourgonnette
The models for FIAT are:
500X VU 5p SUV
Doblò Cargo CA VU 5p Combi
Doblò Cargo VU 2p Plancher cabine
Doblò Cargo VU 2p Plateau
Doblò Cargo VU 3p Fourgonnette
Doblò Cargo VU 4p Fourgonnette
Ducato Benne DC VU 4p Pick-up
Ducato Benne SC VU 2p Pick-up
Ducato CA VU 4p Fourgon
Ducato DC VU 4p Châssis double cabine
Ducato SC VU 2p Châssis cabine
Ducato VU 2p Châssis cabine / coffre
Ducato VU 4p Fourgon
Ducato VU 4p Fourgon vitré
Fiorino VU 3p Fourgonnette
Fiorino VU 4p Fourgonnette
Freemont VU 5p SUV
Fullback VU 4p Plateau
Talento VU 2p Plancher cabine
Talento VU 4p Fourgon
The models for FORD are:
Ranger VU 2p Pick-up
Ranger VU 4p Pick-up
Transit Connect VU 4p Fourgonnette
Transit Connect VU 5p Fourgonnette
Transit Courier VU 3p Fourgonnette
Transit Courier VU 4p Fourgonnette
Transit Custom VU 4p Fourgon
Transit DC VU 4p Châssis cabine
Transit VU 2p Châssis cabine
Transit VU 4p Fourgon
The models for ISUZU are:
D-Max CA VU 4p Pick-up
D-Max DC VU 4p Plateau double cabine
D-Max SC VU 2p Pick-up
N Evolution SC VU 2p Châssis cabine
The models for IVECO are:
Daily VU 2p Châssis cabine
Daily VU 4p Fourgon
Daily VU 4p Fourgon vitré
The models for LADA are:
4X4 VU 3p Fourgon vitré
The models for MERCEDES-BENZ are:
Citan VU 3p Fourgonnette
Citan VU 4p Fourgonnette
Citan VU 5p Combi
Sprinter Benne VU 2p Plateau
Sprinter DC VU 4p Châssis double cabine
Sprinter SC VU 2p Châssis cabine
Sprinter VU 4p Fourgon
Vito Compact VU 4p Fourgon
Vito Extra Long VU 4p Fourgon
Vito Long VU 4p Fourgon
Vito Mixto Compact VU 4p Fourgon
Vito Mixto Extra Long VU 4p Fourgon
Vito Mixto Long VU 4p Fourgon
The models for MITSUBISHI are:
L200 VU 4p Pick-up
The models for NISSAN are:
E-NV200 VU 4p Fourgon
E-NV200 VU 5p Fourgon
NAVARA VU 4p Châssis double cabine
NT400 VU 2p Châssis cabine
NV 200 Cabine Approfondie VU 5p Fourgon
NV 200 Frigorifique VU 4p Fourgon
NV200 VU 4p Fourgon
NV200 VU 5p Fourgon
NV300 VU 4p Fourgon
NV400 - Benne + Coffre VU 2p Pick-up
NV400 - Benne VU 2p Pick-up
NV400 - CA VU 4p Fourgon
NV400 - Caisse VU 2p Châssis cabine
NV400 - Chassis DC VU 4p Châssis double cabine
NV400 - Chassis VU 2p Châssis cabine
NV400 - Planche VU 2p Plancher cabine
NV400 VU 4p Fourgon
Navara 4p Pick-up
The models for OPEL are:
Combo VU 3p Fourgonnette
Combo VU 4p Fourgonnette
Movano Benne DC VU 4p Pick-up
Movano Benne SC VU 2p Pick-up
Movano Cabine Approfondie VU 4p Fourgon
Movano Chassis Cabine DC VU 4p Châssis double cabine
Movano Chassis Cabine SC VU 2p Châssis cabine
Movano Grand Volume VU 3p Châssis cabine / coffre
Movano Plateau ridelles DC VU 4p Plateau double cabine
Movano Plateau ridelles SC VU 2p Plateau
Movano VU 2p Plancher cabine
Movano VU 4p Fourgon
Vivaro Cabine Approfondie VU 4p Fourgon
Vivaro Plancher Cabine VU 2p Plancher cabine
Vivaro VU 4p Fourgon
The models for PEUGEOT are:
Bipper VU 3p Fourgonnette
Bipper VU 4p Fourgonnette
Boxer Benne SC VU 2p Pick-up
Boxer Chassis Cabine DC VU 4p Châssis double cabine
Boxer Chassis Cabine SC VU 2p Châssis cabine
Boxer Plateau Ridelles DC VU 4p Plateau double cabine
Boxer Plateau Ridelles SC VU 2p Plateau
Boxer VU 2p Plancher cabine
Boxer VU 4p Fourgon
Boxer VU 4p Fourgon vitré
Expert VU 2p Plancher cabine
Expert VU 4p Fourgon
Partner Cabine Approfondie VU 4p Fourgonnette
Partner Electric VU 3p Fourgonnette
Partner Electric VU 4p Fourgonnette
Partner Plancher Cabine VU 2p Plancher cabine
Partner VU 3p Fourgonnette
Partner VU 4p Fourgonnette
The models for PIAGGIO are:
Porter Benne SC VU 2p Pick-up
Porter Châssis Cabine SC VU 2p Châssis cabine
Porter VU 5p Fourgon
Porter plateau ridelles SC VU 2p Plateau
The models for RENAULT are:
Kangoo Express VU 3p Fourgonnette
Kangoo Express VU 4p Fourgonnette
Master DC VU 4p Châssis double cabine
Master DC VU 4p Pick-up
Master SC VU 2p Châssis cabine
Master SC VU 2p Pick-up
Master VU 2p Plancher cabine
Master VU 3p Châssis cabine / coffre
Master VU 4p Fourgon
Trafic VU 2p Plancher cabine
Trafic VU 4p Fourgon
The models for TOYOTA are:
Hilux SC VU 2p Châssis cabine
Hilux SC VU 2p Pick-up
Hilux XC VU 2p Pick-up
Proace VU 4p Fourgon
Proace VU 5p Fourgon
The models for VOLKSWAGEN are:
Caddy Maxi Van VU 4p Fourgonnette
Caddy Van VU 4p Fourgonnette
Crafter VU 2p Châssis cabine
Crafter VU 4p Châssis double cabine
Crafter VU 4p Fourgon
Transporter ProCab VU 4p Fourgon
Transporter VU 2p Châssis cabine
Transporter VU 4p Châssis double cabine
Transporter VU 4p Fourgon
Transporter VU 4p Fourgon vitré

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Hope this is what you were looking for.Do let me know if anything in code is not clear

Comment: Amazing, it does just what I needed ! It still has one problem, I cannot change the first box, I get a `Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document` error when I change "voiture" with "Véhicule utilitaire" for instance. Any idea why ? Thanks for your help !

Comment: if you use my code it will change all first box at line 41 and 46 for second & third option. Can you confirm the version of Selenium you are using/browser & OS.

Comment: I don't get it, now it works.. I'm using Selenium 3.3.1 with Chrome on macOS 10.12.4